# Java GC analyses

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I'm not sure if the GC is slow or not by looking at the attached log picture.

How do I go about to analyze the GC log to get to a conclusion?

[image]

Comment: Why dont you try visualvm, it gives result in visual form to understand slowness quickly.

Comment: You pasted the wrong screen. The `Pause` tab may conceal some relevant info.

Comment: I have updated the picture. Not looking for a quick answer I'm looking for somebody guiding me to a tutorial or page which will explain what the values mean.

Comment: 150 ms max pause? That's  not bad.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the stats above are produced by GCViewer: http://github.com/chewiebug/GCViewer.  The README page for the project gives a summary of what the stats mean.

From this we see:

- Freed Memory (8,662.4M):  Total amount of memory that has been freed
- Freed Memory/Min (45.44M/Min): Amount of memory that has been freed per minute
- Total Time (3h10m3ns):  Time data was collected for
- Full GC Performance (n/a): Performance of full collections.
- GC Performance (3,432.6 M/s): Performance of minor collections.

Observations:

1. The amount of garbage collected per minute is reasonable ( < 1M per second )
2. There are no Full GC's ... which is good, since a Full GC incurs a significant pause.
3. By my reckoning<sup>1</sup>, Freed Memory divided by GC Performance should be the number of CPU seconds used by the garbage collector.  That comes out as 2.524 seconds.  If only 2.5 CPU seconds are consumed by the GC over a period of 3 hours, that is a really good result.

In short, your application is not being slowed down appreciable by the Garbage Collector.

---

<sup>1 - Can someone confirm this?</sup>

Comment: I would focus more on individual latencies than overall throughput. Unless the entire runtime is dedicated to solving a single task, that's what really matters. So a single 2.5 second latency _could_ be something to worry about, but several sub-100ms pauses are no big deal.

Comment: Good point.  But the image showing pauses wasn't there when I started working this out.

Comment: Yes... the first screen just wasn't too informative about GC pause issues.

Comment: Hi guys thanks for the feedback. Marko would you say that I need to look at the overall stats, the pause screen?